# How can I reset my docker images when CI via gitlab-runner on MacOSX?

Tags: caching, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I newer in devops and I don't understand basic :

I have a gitlab-runner on my macosx laptop for testing (installed via homebrew). I've linked it into my company's gitlab instance.
I've launch my pipeline : an error during install-job : I've forgot to install one dependency.
I re-launch pipeline and I see before_script is ignored because "Restored from cache".

So my question is : how can I clean this cache (not my pipeline cache folders).

Do I have to run a command on my laptop via gitlab-runner cli ?
Do I have to run a command on my laptop via docker cli ?
Can I have a variable or button I've missed on gitlab web instance ?
Their is a directive to add into .gitlab-ci.yml file ?
And why they said "No URL provided, cache will not be downloaded from shared cache server. Instead a local version of cache will be extracted." ?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

**My .gitlab-ci.yml :**

```
stages:
  - install
  - build
  - db_create
  - test

image: bitnami/laravel

cache:
  key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
  paths:
    - vendor/
    - node_modules/

before_script:
  - echo "Install make:"
  - sudo apt-get -y install make
  - echo "Configure composer path & check platform requirements :"
  - export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"
  - php composer check-platform-reqs

job:install-dev:
  stage: install
  except:
    - master
  before_script:
    - echo "Starting dev stage 'install'."
  script: make install
  after_script:
    - echo "End of dev 'install' stage."

job:install-prod:
  stage: install
  only:
    - master
  before_script:
    - echo "Starting prod stage 'install'."
  script: make install-prod
  after_script:
    - echo "End of prod 'install' stage."

job:build-dev:
  stage: build
  except:
    - master
  before_script:
    - echo "Starting dev stage 'build'."
  script: npm run dev
  after_script:
    - echo "End of dev 'build' stage."
  when: on_success

job:build-prod:
  stage: build
  only:
    - master
  before_script:
    - echo "Starting prod stage 'build'."
  script: npm run prod
  after_script:
    - echo "End of prod 'build' stage."
  when: on_success

job:creation_db:
  stage: db_create
  before_script:
    - echo "Starting stage 'db_create'."
  script:
    - php artisan db:create
    - php artisan migrate
  after_script:
    - echo "End of 'db_create' stage."
  when: on_success

job:test:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - echo "Starting stage 'test'."
  script:
    - php artisan test
    - php artisan blade:lint
    - vendor/bin/phpstan analyse
    # - vendor/friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer/php-cs-fixer fix --config .php-cs-fixer.dist.php --allow-risky=yes
  after_script:
    - echo "End of 'test' stage."
  when: on_success
```

**Response of pipeline :**

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.10.1 (dcfb4b66)
  on EE-mac-RB.local nVmjJEbX, system ID: s_d8f303928373
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:02
Using Docker executor with image bitnami/laravel ...
WARNING: Container based cache volumes creation is disabled. Will not create volume for "/cache"
Pulling docker image bitnami/laravel ...
Using docker image sha256:6a5a226b784dd20deecbd95d3cdf7fd925d424005cc76fae7c2d8e930f9c9a06 for bitnami/laravel with digest bitnami/laravel@sha256:aa0597cb6f29e9faf30a9b2b8521d641cfe780ead168a6a987ac1029f971667e ...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on runner-nvmjjebx-project-88-concurrent-0 via EE-mac-RB.local...
Getting source from Git repository
00:05
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/economiedenergie/arkea/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out 87aea52f as detached HEAD (ref is feature/unitTests)...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Restoring cache
00:00
Checking cache for feature-unittests-3...
No URL provided, cache will not be downloaded from shared cache server. Instead a local version of cache will be extracted. 
Successfully extracted cache
[...]
```

This is my `~/.gitlab-runner/config.toml`

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800   

[[runners]]
  name = "EE-mac-RB.local"  
  url = "https://gitlab.mycompany.tld/"
  id = 26
  token = "***********"
  token_obtained_at = 2023-04-13T09:38:26Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = true
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock","/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [clear the cache by changing the `cache:key:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#clear-the-cache-by-changing-cachekey) to a different value. If you do not set a `cache:key:` the value is [assumed to be `default`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#cachekey) (and therefore will be restored every time).

Alternatively, you can use the button in the "Pipelines" page in the web UI to [clear the cache manually](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#clear-the-cache-manually).

---

If you are using the `shell` executor, keep in mind that some software may also create caches outside of the GitLab job workspace that are not controlled by the `cahce:` keyword in your CI YAML configuration. You should refer to the documentation of the specific software you are using in such cases.

Comment: I use the cache:key and clearing cache manually via UI, but it's only for app caches right ? Vendor and node-modules for example.... I don't want to clear these caches but the docker cache like I said.

Comment: apologies @Chenille33 I think I have misunderstood the question and should have asked for clarification or additional details. Are you using the shell executor or docker executor? If you are using the docker executor, the [`disable_cache` setting](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnersdocker-section) may be what you are looking for. If not, could you please update your question with the full job output to which you refer in the question and your job configuration/script?

Comment: No problem :) I'm so newer than I can't answere if I use shell or docker (docker I imagine....). I'll put more information in my question, my bad.